# The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: -wx------

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have changed permission using hdfs command. Still it showing same error.

> The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: -wx------

Java Program that I am executing.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver;

public class HiveCreateDb {
   private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      // Register driver and create driver instance

         Class.forName(driverName);

/*  try {
  Class.forName(driverName);
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
  print("Couldn't find Gum");

} */     // get connection

      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://", "", "");

      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

      stmt.executeQuery("CREATE DATABASE userdb");
      System.out.println("Database userdb created successfully.");

      con.close();
   }
}
```

It is giving a runtime error for connecting hive.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------
[image]

Comment: which command exactly?

Comment: $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive

Comment: have you tried using hdfs sudo user in your hive connection string

Comment: Have you tried removing the directory `hadoop fs -rm -r /tmp/hive` and letting Hive to create it with the appropiate permissions?

Comment: I had to give permission on the local linux filesystem for /tmp/hive. Like: chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive/

Answer (score 5):

Try this

`hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive/`;

I had a similar issue while running a hive query, using the `-R` resolved it.

Comment: No, it didn't work for me. The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------

Comment: On my `Mac`, the above command fixes the permission issue but once I launch the `hive shell` and close it, the problem re-appears. I've found that launching `hive` shell removes the *write permission* from `/tmp/hive` for **'o' (others)** and **'g' (groups)**. While `beeline` shell doesn't suffer with this issue, the fact that `hive` shell exhibits this behaviour makes me think there's something wrong with the configuration on my PC

Comment: @y2k Hive CLI is deprecated in favor of beeline

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the previous answers, if your username is something like 'cloudera' (you could be using cloudera manager/cloudera quickstart as your implementation platform), you could do the following:

> sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive/;

Remember that in hadoop, 'hdfs' is the superuser and not 'root' or 'cloudera'.

Comment: Or, you can just `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs` and forget about the "sudo"; that env variable takes precedence over the current Linux user name *(unless you are using Kerberos auth but that's another story)*

Comment: Above command will give you error Hadoop command not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do chmod (777)... The correct is (733):

Hive 0.14.0 and later: HDFS root scratch directory for Hive jobs, which gets created with write all (733) permission. For each connecting user, an HDFS scratch directory ${hive.exec.scratchdir}/ is created with ${hive.scratch.dir.permission}.

Try to do this with hdfs user:

```
    hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/hive
    hdfs dfs -chown hive /tmp/hive/$HADOOP_USER_NAME
    hdfs dfs -chmod 733 /tmp/hive/$HADOOP_USER_NAME
    hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/hive/$HADOOP_USER_NAME
    hdfs dfs -chown $HADOOP_USER_NAME /tmp/hive/$HADOOP_USER_NAME
    hdfs dfs -chmod 700 /tmp/hive/$HADOOP_USER_NAME
```

This works, instead you can change scratchdir path with (from hive):

```
set hive.exec.scratchdir=/somedir_with_permission/subdir...
```

more info: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration

Answer (score 1):

We are executing spark job in local mode. That means there is no writable permission to the directory /tmp/hive in local (linux) machine.

So execute `chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive`. That solved my issue.

Referred from:::
[The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx--------- (on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41205993/3150936)

Comment: you all guys referring to HDFS  , but me running on windows10 machine, local laptop.  how to fix the issue

Comment: If it happens in the windows what would be the solution

Comment: @BdEngineer Use winutils exe to execute same command. Make sure your winutils version is supported by hadoop.