# The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx--------- (on Linux)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

**The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx--------**

Hi, The following Spark code i was executing in Eclipse of CDH 5.8 & getting above RuntimeExeption

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("HiveConnector");
    final JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(sparkContext);

    DataFrame df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM test_hive_table1");
    //df.show();
    df.count();
 }
```

According to Exception **/tmp/hive on HDFS** should be writable, however we are executing spark job in local mode. That means there is no writable permission to the directory **/tmp/hive** in local (linux) file system, not HDFS.

So I had executed below command to gave permission.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive
```

Now it is working for me.

If you are getting the same issue during execution of spark job in cluster mode you should configure below property in ***hive-site.xml*** file of hive conf folder and restart hive server.

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hive</value>
    <description>Scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.scratch.dir.permission</name>
    <value>777</value>
    <description>The permission for the user-specific scratch directories that get created in the root scratch directory </description>
  </property>
```

Comment: you got exception and you fixed it. So what is the problem here ?? I mean what are you trying to ask as a question here?

Answer (score 2):

use proper 64bit [winutils](http://letstalkspark.blogspot.in/2016/02/getting-started-with-spark-on-window-64.html)   and set permission

winutils.exe chmod -R 777 \tmp\hive

```
 System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\Users\\Hadoop_home")
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("c:\\tmp\\metastore_db"))
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("c:\\tmp\\spark-warehouse"))
    SparkSession.builder().config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:\\temp\\").master("local").appName("spark session for testing").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
  }
```