# Hive on windows : The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable

Tags: apache-spark, hive, orc

I'm trying to convert a Spark application to use ORC output storage instead of Parquet format.
After modifying my code, I have the below error when running the application on Windows:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS
> should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-    at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
>   ... 73 more
```

First, i found strange it can't write with the `rw-rw-rw-` permissions but whatever, I tried to change this directory permissions with Hadoop's winutils as descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504946/3783432) :

```
winutils.exe chmod -R 777 \tmp
```

But still the same error...

Moreover, I also tried to delete the directory and the app automaticaly rebuilt it with the 733 permissions but still says it can't write...

**EDIT** : This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409838/the-root-scratch-dir-tmp-hive-on-hdfs-should-be-writable-current-permissions) question because my problem stands on Windows platform.

Comment: @user8371915 This is not a duplicate, my problem stands on Windows

Comment: @user8371915 I saw this post and tried to apply the solution as described above, this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I think this actually is a duplicate - the linked question is also on Windows.