# sparkpy insists that root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable

Tags: hive, pyspark, spark-hive

I am trying to run a pyspark program that access the hive server. The program terminates by throwing the error

`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxrwxr-x;`

Now, [The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: -wx------](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409838/the-root-scratch-dir-tmp-hive-on-hdfs-should-be-writable-current-permissions) suggests that I should chmod it 777. I did.

`drwxrwxrwx   - hadoopuser supergroup          0 2019-07-03 06:39 /tmp/hive`

However, pyspark still throws the same error.

Because of that, I decided to change the scratch dir folder to /tmp/sparkpy. I registered this change at hive-site.xml

I restarted the hiveserver2 and Beeline confirmed that the change is registered.

```
+------------------------------------+
|                set                 |
+------------------------------------+
| hive.exec.scratchdir=/tmp/sparkpy  |
+------------------------------------+
1 row selected (0.028 seconds)
```

However, pyspark is still stuck at /tmp/hive and insists that it's not writeable.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this same issue. Finally, I got the answer /tmp/hive location is present in your local system.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /tmp
```

Above command fixed issue for me.